# Jsch - Multiple channels per session

Tags: java, session, ssh, channel, jsch

There is a problem, when I try to fire second command in the same session using Jsch API

```
package examples.com;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import com.jcraft.jsch.Channel;
import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelExec;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Session;

public class TempFile {

private static Session connectSession(String userName, String password, String host) throws Exception {
        JSch.setLogger(new MyLogger());
        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        Session session = null;
        try {
            session = jsch.getSession(userName, host, 22);
            session.setPassword(password);
            session.setTimeout(10000);
            java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
            config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
            session.setConfig(config);
            session.connect();                      
        }
        catch (JSchException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
        return session;
    }

    private static void connectChannel(Session session, String command) throws JSchException, IOException {
        System.out.println(command);
        Channel channel = null;
        channel = session.openChannel("exec");
        ((ChannelExec) channel).setCommand(command);
        InputStream in = channel.getInputStream();
        channel.connect();
        System.out.println("channel.isConnected()  "+channel.isConnected());
        setInAndOutStream(channel, in);
        channel.disconnect();
        System.out.println("channel.isClosed()  "+channel.isClosed());
    }

    private static void setInAndOutStream(Channel channel, InputStream in) throws IOException, JSchException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        StringBuilder outPutResult = new StringBuilder("");
        int exitStatus = -100;
        String output;
        while (true) {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    String result = br.readLine();
                    if (result == null)
                        break;
                    outPutResult.append(result);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                    break;
                }
            }
            output = outPutResult.toString();

            if (channel.isClosed()) {
                exitStatus = channel.getExitStatus();
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(exitStatus);
        System.out.println(output);
    }

    private static void executeCommand(Session session, String command) throws JSchException, IOException{
        connectChannel(session,command);
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("starting");
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            Session session = connectSession("username", "password", "host");
            if(session!=null) {
                executeCommand(session, "ls");
                executeCommand(session, "cp out.txt copy.txt");

                session.disconnect();
            }
        } catch (JSchException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("done..");
    }

}
```

It works fine if I use Linux machine as a host.
But if I try to connect to Windows Server 2008 machine having openssh it fails to execute second command i.e. "executeCommand(session, "cp out.txt copy.txt");" it returns status 255.

What must have gone wrong?? Do we need to set some option in ssh configuration file to support this one session and multiple channel??

Comment: It could be that the server's SSHD implementation just doesn't support multiple channels. This seems more of a server problem than a client (i.e. JSch) one.

Comment: First of all thanks for reply.. Yes I do understand it must be server problem. But how do I make server to support this one session multiple channel.?? I have tried setting MaxSessions option on sshd_config file on server side, as I have read somewhere that it maps to number of channels on JSch api. But it didn't helped either in above scenario.

Answer (score 0):

try changing

```
        channel = session.openChannel("exec");
```

with

```
    channel = session.openChannel("shell");
```